# PHP Class to Session THEN Session To Class

Tags: php, class, session

When user login my system I am holding its info on session.

Code:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setUyeid($row["UyeId"]);
$user->setAdsoyad($row["AdSoyad"]);
$user->setEmail($row["Email"]);
$user->setTelefon($row["Telefon"]);
$user->setOnay($row["Onay"]);
$user->setYetki($row["Yetki"]);
$user->setReferansid($row["ReferansId"]);
$user->setEngelbitistarihi($row["EngelBitisTarihi"]);
$user->setPremiumuyelikbitistarihi($row["PremiumUyelikBitisTarihi"]);
$user->setSmsabonelikbitistarihi($row["SmsAbonelikBitisTarihi"]);
$uye->setIp($IP);

$_SESSION["User"] = $user;
```

After login I try to access my session as a class but I couldn't do it.

```
$user = new User();
$user = $_SESSION["User"];
$user->test(); //IT IS NOT WORKING I HAVE ERROR
```

I can not do it. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
session_start();

$user = new User();
$user->setUyeid($row["UyeId"]);
$user->setAdsoyad($row["AdSoyad"]);
$user->setEmail($row["Email"]);
$user->setTelefon($row["Telefon"]);
$user->setOnay($row["Onay"]);
$user->setYetki($row["Yetki"]);
$user->setReferansid($row["ReferansId"]);
$user->setEngelbitistarihi($row["EngelBitisTarihi"]);
$user->setPremiumuyelikbitistarihi($row["PremiumUyelikBitisTarihi"]);
$user->setSmsabonelikbitistarihi($row["SmsAbonelikBitisTarihi"]);
$user->setIp($IP);

$_SESSION["User"] = $user;
```

After login:

```
session_start();

// assigning the user-object here is not necessary, it is unserialized
$user = $_SESSION["User"];

// I assume your user-object actually has a method 'test'
$user->test();
```

Comment: ofc there is sessions method.

Comment: the code is not understand it is a object of User class. Just I have error.